# How to get rid of partitions on my external dual hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I have a mediasonic HUR5-SU3 dual external hard drive. I put two WD 3tb hard drives in with raid1 set. So I should have a total of 3tb useable space. When I formatted it. It only allowed the partition to be 349gb.  When I format them on their own. I can format them to their full 3tb space.
I do see I have two other partitions. It would allow me to “Turn one of them on”, so that I could have another part useable. The third partition won’t give me the option to be used at all. So really it only lets me use 2tb of my 3 tb drive. This can’t be right.
Even though I have it in raid 1. The second disk (which I believe is the first disk in the actual machine) does show up on disk management.
So I took them out.  And only disk 1 had anything on it. So it appears raid 1 is not mirroring like it should. Which makes it pointless. I also don’t get why I don’t have any partitions if I use them separately. 
What I asking basically:
1)  Is there a way to get rid of the partitions.
2)  Any suggestions on why the second drive might not be “mirrioring”.

Comment: Did you initialize both drives with GPT and not MBR? 1. You can delete partitions, but you need at least 1.  Delete via **diskpart** in windows.  **select drive #** whatever it is.  **clean** and exit no partitions left.  You can also zero out sector 0.  Once you verify you have GPT, if you still have issues your hardware might not support 48 bit LBA.

Comment: Maximum partition size in MBR is 2.2TB. Else use GPT.

Answer (score 0):

This seems very unfortunate, @goalsetter88! I'd recommend you to backup your data from the array somewhere else before proceeding. [Getting rid of all the partitions](http://support.wdc.com/KnowledgeBase/answer.aspx?ID=3865)
 would require you to erase everything on the HDDs. As the guys above already mentioned, in order to use the full 3 TB capacity, you'd need to [re-initialize](http://support.wdc.com/KnowledgeBase/answer.aspx?ID=1018) the HDDs in GPT, instead of MBR (due to its 2.2 TB limit).

As for 2) I'd suggest you make sure you have the updated drivers for your SATA controllers & chipset from the mobo manufacturer's website. A fresh start of the whole storage configuration might be a good idea altogether.

Give these a try and keep us posted!